# How to remove extra space inside of jQuery UI dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

here is my dialog box

[image]

I want to delete or remove the extra spaces inside of dialog box. How can I achieve it?

for extra details here my **HTML**

```
<div id="beneficiaries_window">
  <?php
    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM beneficiary WHERE id = '$id'";
    $result1 = mysql_query($sql1);
  ?>
  <table style="border: 2px solid black;margin:auto;">
    <tr>
      <th><center>Name<center></th>
      <th><center>Action</center></th>
    </tr>
  <?php             
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
      echo "<tr class='beneficiaries_rows' id='".$row1['id']."'>";
      echo "<td>".$row1['name']."</td>";
      echo "<td>";
      echo "<button class='edit_beneficiaries'>EDIT</button>";
      echo "<button class='del_beneficiaries'>X</button>";
      echo "</td><br/>";
      echo "</tr>";
    }
  ?>
  </table>
  </div>
  <button class="beneficiaries" name="beneficiaries">Beneficiaries</button>
```

and **jQuery script**

```
jQuery("#beneficiaries_window").dialog({
  modal: true,
  resizable: false,
  draggable: false,
  autoOpen: false,
  buttons:[{
    text: "Close",
    click: function(){
      jQuery(this).dialog("close");
    }
  }]
});

//beneficiaries open dialog
jQuery(".beneficiaries").click(function(event){
  jQuery("#beneficiaries_window").dialog("open");
    event.preventDefault();
  });
```

but in my **firebug** i see this `<br>'s` but their is no `<br>` inside of the `<div>`

[image]

how can i remove this im clueless about this extra spacing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it has extra spacing because of this `<br>`

```
<?php             
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
  echo "<tr class='beneficiaries_rows' id='".$row1['id']."'>";
  echo "<td>".$row1['name']."</td>";
  echo "<td>";
  echo "<button class='edit_beneficiaries'>EDIT</button>";
  echo "<button class='del_beneficiaries'>X</button>";

  echo "</td><br/>";          <----THIS <br/> make the extra spacing

  echo "</tr>";
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#div_id').dialog({
        title   : 'Add User',
        position: { my: "center", at: "center", of: window },
        width   : 1000,
        height  : 500,
        modal   : true,
        closeOnEscape: false
    });
```

you can define width, height in it, define its width accordingly.

Comment: I give my height a **150** but still the extra spacing is still their even i made it **20** it give me scroll but extra space is still their.

Comment: Check the dom if there is some padding coming with the div.

Comment: i get it sir thank you. I echo `<br>` thats why it has extra spacing